# How do I make HttpClient send a request body?

Tags: http, f#

I've seen various answers to this question in C# but I'm baffled why the same solution doesn't seem to work in F#.

```
let client = new HttpClient();
let msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "http://localhost:9999/")
msg.Version <- System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10 
let body = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("HTTP MESSAGE")
msg.Content <- new ByteArrayContent(body) 
let task = Async.AwaitTask (client.SendAsync(msg))
```

At first I thought the issue was related to the HTTP 1.1 expect-100 behavior which the server side doesn't support it. But after changing to HTTP 1.0 this is what the client actually sends:

```
POST / HTTP/1.0
Host: localhost:9999
Content-Length: 12
```

And that's it. It's still not sending the HttpRequestMessage.Content. What am I missing here?

Comment: Replacing `localhost` with the publicly available `posttestserver.com`, I can't reproduce the described behaviour: http://www.posttestserver.com/data/2016/10/13/ploeh/14.57.35179411777

Comment: Apart from that, you ought to run `task` using something like `Async.RunSynchronously`.